# Are there memory performance benefits in using projections between stages in MongoDB's aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb

A collection may have multiple columns that each contain substantial data like article content or image data etc.

When using aggregation pipeline stages, I would assume there would be benefits to trim down the fields using projection, so we only pass required fields to subsequent stages to help with memory usage.

A trivial example: we have a requirement to find all `articles` that don't have a matching author from an `authors` collection. I would assume that we would not project unnecessary article fields onwards. The same with the `$lookup` to authors where we only need and id for this purpose. Demo:

```
db.getCollection("articles").aggregate(

    [
        {
            $match: {
                somecolumn: { "$ne": null, $exists: true }
            }
        },

        {
            $project: { 
                id: 1,
                authorId: 1
            }
        },

        {
            $lookup: {
                      from: "authors",
                      let: { author: "$authorId" },
                      pipeline: [
                        {
                          $match: {
                              $expr:
                                {
                                    $eq: ["$$author","$id"] }
                              }

                        },
                        { $project: { id: 1, } }
                      ],
                      as: "author"
                    }
        },

        {
            $match: {
                "author.0": {$exists: false}
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Am I correct in this assumption or do the internal processes work differently?

Comment: your projection is not legal syntax - you cannot mix inclusion and exclusions.  which one do you actually use?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky spot on, I typed up a pseudo example that was incorrect. Have adjusted. Thanks

Comment: btw, I would recommend rather than using "author.0": {$exists:false} just use {"author":{$ne:[]}}

Comment: the way things work internally, it will be faster to do normal (localField/foreignField) $lookup and not worry about $project inside $lookup than to switch to more expensive expressive $lookup to add the projection.  That's the case in all versions up to the next major one, and it's likely to stay that way in the future as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When using aggregation pipeline stages, I would assume there would be
>   benefits to trim down the fields using projection, so we only pass
>   required fields to subsequent stages to help with memory usage.

Yes, this is correct. Each aggregation stage has a memory limit, and working within this limit will ensure that there will not be performance issues.

From the manual ([pipeline memory restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#agg-memory-restrictions)):

> Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. If a stage
>   exceeds this limit, MongoDB will produce an error. To allow for the
>   handling of large datasets, use the `allowDiskUse` option to enable
>   aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files.

When the query uses the `allowDiskUse` it will affect the performance, as using disk is very much slower than the memory.

In addition, here are some important practices:

- Use as less stages as possible; more stages means that the documents
  need to be examined at each stage. This is additional processing and
  resources.
- Avoid unnecessary `$project` stages.
- Specifying certain stages at the beginning of the pipeline is important. The stages,    `$match` and `$sort` can use indexes only in the initial stages. Also, `$match` and `$limit` can reduce the number of documents to process down the pipeline if used early in the pipeline.
- Use `explain` and study the query plans to find if indexes are being used (in `$match` and `$sort`) or any indexes need defining for query optimization. Note that indexes work little bit differently with aggregations and also not all stages can use indexes.

As such aggregation framework can automatically re-order some stages for optimization. For further details see this documentation on [aggregation pipeline optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/).

Comment: Thanks, I actually went through the docs but missed the section on the [limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#agg-memory-restrictions) Please can you update your answer to include that link to help other users. Thanks again!

Comment: this answer is incorrect, I'm writing up an alternate answer, but just wanted to point that out.

Comment: see my answer for why you should not include unnecessary extra $project stages.  Note that 100MBs limit only applies to blocking stages (i.e. grouping, sorting full result set) not to streaming stages which pass documents through the pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the only place you want to have $project is as the very last stage in order to return only the needed fields back to the client, in some cases maybe renaming or recomputing them.

You do *not* need to have $project earlier in the pipeline to "trim down the fields" because the [aggregation already does dependency analysis](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization) and only gets the fields that are needed in the pipeline.

Here is an example, shown via `explain`:

```
db.foo.explain().aggregate({$group:{_id:"$fieldA", count:{$sum:1}}})
{
  "stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {

            },
            "fields" : {
                "fieldA" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "snv.foo",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {

                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "EOF"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$fieldA",
            "count" : {
                "$sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Even though I have no projection, you can see that only `fieldA` is being returned to the rest of the pipeline.

The only scenarios where it's necessary to add early `$project`stage would be to work around a bug or limitation in aggregation's own dependency analysis, but it should be avoided routinely.

Comment: I have just tested this and it's not quite the same for my plan. If I leave the `$project` in at stage 2, I get: `{ 
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "postCode" : {
                        "$ne" : null, 
                        "$exists" : true
                    }
                }, 
                "fields" : {
                    "postCode" : 1.0, 
                    "_id" : 1.0
                }, 
                "queryPlanner" : {` which includes the **fields** object which is not included normally.

Comment: Excluding the `$project` at stage 2, I get: `{ 
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "postCode" : {
                        "$ne" : null, 
                        "$exists" : true
                    }
                }, 
                "queryPlanner" : {` where the fields object is missing.

Comment: your sample pipeline without $project actually *keeps* all the fields.  So no fields object is passed to query subsystem.  Mine uses $group so only a single field is needed.  That's why I said if you do need to change which fields should be returned, do it in the last stage.

Comment: Yes, correct it keeps all the fields. I assume this means they all passed to the next stage? Can we take this to a quick chat - I understand that group by will not include the fields, but seems different for a find().

Comment: I'm not online continuously but basically think of projection as being equivalent of <> in this SQL:   select <> from xxx ... since it defines which fields you want to get back to the client, it should logically go last in sequential stages. In cases of $group which completely defines the fields it's creating, it's simply unnecessary.

Comment: I absolutely get that projection is equivalent to SQL Select-List, but this is not the same. I have run several explain scenario and is not simply moving a $project to the end of the plan. Update your test aggregate query to match the example in the query. In addition, if no $project is specified in the $lookup, then **all** the fields are returned to the next stage. As per the docs, this is the equiv to:

Comment: cont. ``SELECT *, stockdata
FROM orders
WHERE stockdata IN (SELECT warehouse, instock
                    FROM warehouses
                    WHERE stock_item= orders.item
                    AND instock >= orders.ordered );`` which limits the fields returned in the Subquery to just `warehouse, instock`. If we left the `$project` out in this stage, then all fields would be output into the 'as: "author"' and passed forward to the next stage - unless I am mistaken. If the lookup collection specified has many fields with large amounts of data, then surely this impacts performance?

Comment: as it turns out, it would be slower to do field filtering inside of $lookup in majority of the cases.  like I said, extra stages are extra work.  in order to save overall execution time, they would have to significantly reduce the number of _documents_ being processed.  Reducing the number of fields is simply not going to have the effect of speeding up the overall aggregation.